# Two array merge to form new array of key value pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
Array a=['india','germany','russia'];
Array b=[100,70,60];
Array c =[
{Country:"india", val:100},
{Country:"germany", val:70},
{Country:"russia", val:60},];
```

> i want the result array like Array c.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop and add both indexes together

Comment: Atleast explain what have you tried till now.

Comment: try this `const c = b.map((index,obj) => ({ country: a[index], val: b }));`

Comment: @SelvaS Thankyou for your try. i got the result as [ { "val": [ 100, 50, 25 ] }, { "val": [ 100, 50, 25 ] }, { "val": [ 100, 50, 25 ] } ]. it is wrong. my desired result shows in question

Comment: My bad. It is `const c = b.map((index,value) => ({ country: a[index], val: value }));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let a=['india','germany','russia'];
let b=[100,70,60];
let c=a.map((country,index)=>{
    return {
        "Country":country,
        "val":b[index]
    };
});
```

This code loops through the first array, (In case the number of elements are different for both arrays, use the array with smallest length or use default value) and sets the value of the array as the object with those properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['india','germany','russia'];
b=[100,70,60];
const c=[]
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
data={
"Country":a[i],
"val":b[i]
}
c.push(data)
}
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a=['india','germany','russia'];
let b=[100,70,60];
let c = [];
for(let i in a) {
    c.push({country: a[i], val: b[i]});
}
console.log(c);
```